# Is there a way to turn off asynchronous outputs in VSCode Jupyter Notebook file?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I was wondering if there is a way to turn off asynchronous outputting in VSCode using a Jupyter Notebook. When executing a program in VSCode the outputs of each cell are shown below it as it cycles, however, ideally id like all outputs to be in the same place for presentation sake.

Any help would be awesome!

Basically the code is organised into cells, and each cell will print its output as soon as it has been executed. So the format goes:

Code cell,
Output,
Code cell,
Output
...

whereas id like it to be:

Code cell,
Code cell,
Code cell,
Output
...

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHawV.jpg)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  Can you show us some of the code, or a sample screenshot that shows the issue?

Comment: @Harry Barnard There should be no way to achieve this. Why not use .py or merge all cells?